# Symfony Doctrine генерирует дополнительную таблицу зачем-то

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Symfony Doctrine генерирует несколько таблиц сразу при команде:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Конкретно названия таблиц этих таблиц - "`words_themewords`" и "`theme_words`".

При чем использование идет у таблицы `words_themewords`, а структура у нее вообще непонятно откуда взялась:

```
1   words_id    
2   themewords_id
```

Есть 1 модель - `ThemeWords`:

```
namespace Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * ThemeWords
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="theme_words")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ThemeWords
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity\Words", mappedBy="theme")
     */
    private $words;
```

Есть вторая модель - Words:
namespace Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Words
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="words")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity\Repository\WordRepository")
 */
class Words
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity\ThemeWords")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="theme_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $theme;
```

Так же отчищал кэш doctrine и вообще через app/console clear cache

Answer (score 3):

А для реализации такой связи реляционной БД нужна промежуточная таблица, в твоем случае `words_themewords`.

Дополнительно рекомендую ознакомиться тем, как представляется связь многие-ко-многим в реляционных БД.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.